# Have a javascript function privately track it's number of calls

Tags: javascript, closures

I'm trying to figure out how I can have a javascript function privately track the number of times it has been called. The objective is to be able to query this value in the console during debugging by doing `func.run`

My first attempt:

```
function asdf() { 
  if (!asdf.run) {
    asdf.run = 0;
  } else {
    asdf.run++;
    console.error('run: ' + asdf.run);
  }
  console.error('asdf.run def: ');
  console.error(asdf.run);
}
asdf();
```

---

This is a good lesson of why one should ALWAYS aim to use `===` in nearly all javascript booleans, cause they could secretly be `==`

Comment: I think you forgot to include the output of your original function in your post :)

Comment: I have no idea which answer to accept.

Comment: I found this post helpful when learning about javascript coercion rules http://webreflection.blogspot.com/2010/10/javascript-coercion-demystified.html most of the rules make sense (I actually like that 0 and "" are falsey), but there are definately some areas that will trip you up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Closures are the way to go here:

```
var asdf = (function () {
    var runs = 0;
    var f = function () {
        ++runs;
        // your function here
    };
    f.runs = function () {
        return runs;
    };
    return f;
}());
```

Usage:

```
asdf();
asdf();
asdf.runs(); // 2
asdf();
asdf.runs(); // 3
```

Or, you could use a mocking framework like (<sub>shameless self plug</sub>) [Myrtle](https://github.com/spadgos/myrtle).

Comment: @Devin G Rhode - the edit you've made is fine. The reason I avoid multiple `var` statements is because of JSLint. Doug Crockford's reasoning is thus: "In languages with block scope, it is usually recommended that variables be declared at the site of first use. But because JavaScript does not have block scope, it is wiser to declare all of a function's variables at the top of the function. **It is recommended that a single var statement be used per function.**"

Answer (score 2):

Your first try would work fine except you've forgotten that `0` is a "falsy" value in JavaScript, so on the first run and every run thereafter `!this.run` will evaluate to `true` and your `else` block will never be reached. This is pretty easy to work around.

```
function foo() {
  if(typeof(foo.count) == 'undefined') {
    foo.count = 0;
  } else {
    foo.count++;
  }
  console.log(foo.count);
}

foo(); # => 0
foo(); # => 1
foo(); # => 2
# ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't actually tried this, but I looked up "static function variables in JavaScript", and I found [this resource](http://www.tipstrs.com/tip/1084/Static-variables-in-Javascript).  I think the main difference between what you wrote and what's in that solution is how the first run of the function is detected.  Perhaps your *!asdf.run* test is not working the way you thought it was, and you should use *typeof asdf.run == 'undefined'* to test instead.

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is a method that I came up with that does not require the function to be modified at all.

So if you have this.

```
function someFunction() {
   doingThings();
}
```

you could add a counter like this...

```
addCounter(this, "someFunction");
```

where this is the scope you are in, you could use any object that has a method you want to count.

Here's the code for it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function someFunc() {
            console.log("I've been called!");
        };

        // pass an object, this or window and a function name
        function wrapFunction(parent, functionName) {
            var count = 0, orig = parent[functionName];
            parent[functionName] = function() {
                count++;
                return orig.call(this, Array.prototype.slice(arguments));
            }

            parent[functionName].getCount = function() {
                return count;
            };
        }

        var someObj = {
            someFunc: function() {
                console.log("this is someObj.someFunc()");
            }                               
        }                                   


        wrapFunction(this, "someFunc");
        wrapFunction(someObj, "someFunc");
        someFunc();           

        someObj.someFunc();
        someObj.someFunc();
        someObj.someFunc();

        console.log("Global someFunc called " + someFunc.getCount() + " time" + (someFunc.getCount() > 1 ? "s" : "")) ;
        console.log("Global someObj.someFunc called " + someObj.someFunc.getCount() + " time" + (someObj.someFunc.getCount() > 1 ? "s" : "")) ;
    </script>                                                                   
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, `!asdf.run` is a form of the double equals operator `==` and I had set `asdf.run` to `0` so it was false.

Using the triple equals `===` **:**

`typeof asdf.run === "undefined"` for the boolean solves my issue.

So a final usable and useful version:

```
function sdf() { 
  if (typeof sdf.run === "undefined") { sdf.run = 0; }
  sdf.run++;
}
```

To query the number of times `sdf` has been called:

```
sdf.run;
```

To actually make this variable private and protect it from change, one would implement a closure.

Answer (score 0):

```
//using a closure and keeping your functions out of the global scope 
var myApp = (function() {
   //counter is a private member of this scope
   var retObj = {}, counter = 0;
   //function fn() has privileged access to counter
   retObj.fn = function() {
       counter++;
       console.log(counter);
    };
    //set retObj to myApp variable
    return retObj;
}());


myApp.fn(); //count = 1
myApp.fn(); //count = 2
myApp.fn(); //count = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't necessarily need a closure. Just use a static variable.

```
var foo = function(){
    alert( ++foo.count || (foo.count = 1) );
}


// test
function callTwice(f){ f(); f(); }
callTwice(foo)                  // will alert 1 then 2
```

or

```
callTwice( function bar(){           
    alert( ++bar.count || (bar.count = 1) );
});                             // will alert 1 then 2
```

the second one is a *named anonymous function*. And note this syntax:

```
var foo = function bar(){ /* foo === bar in here */ }
```