# Javascript: What is a function property and what is it's significance?

Tags: javascript

I came across this piece of information in the book [You Don't Know JS: `this` & Object Prototypes](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/blob/master/this%20%26%20object%20prototypes/ch1.md#itself):

> ```
> function foo(num) {
>     console.log( "foo: " + num );
>     this.count++;
> }
>
> foo.count = 0; 
> for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
>     if (i > 5) {
>         foo( i );
>     }
> }
> ```

Now, it's mentioned afterwards that...

> When the code executes `foo.count = 0`, indeed it’s adding a property `count` to the function object `foo`.

I don't understand what is a function's property and how it is being declared this way.

I do understand that a function is also an object in JS but I don't understand the significance of a function's property. Also, an object's property is defined this way:

```
var obj = {name: 'value'};
```

But how can `foo.count=0` -- out of the scope of `function foo()` -- declare a property under `foo()`.

Comment: You could have also said `obj.name = 'value'` to set the object's property. It is exactly the same when the object is a function.

Comment: @trincot: The book actually makes the very same point; the code ends with `console.log( foo.count ); // 0 -- WTF?`, that was not replicated by OP.

Comment: I suppose the question is more about `foo.count` then.

Comment: Btw, `this.count` and `foo.count` are different. Just in case if you don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this code:

```
var foo = { prop: 1 };   
foo.count = 0; 
console.log(foo.count); // 0
```

`foo` can be any object. It does not have to be initialised as `{}`. It could be an array (e.g. `[1, 2, 3]`), a date (e.g. `new Date()`), any other object, and so also a function:

```
var foo = function (num) {
    console.log( "foo: " + num );
};

foo.count = 0; 
console.log(foo.count);
```

I wrote the function as a function expression assigned to a variable, to highlight the point that `foo` is assigned an object. But it also works with a function declaration syntax:

```
function foo(num) {
    console.log( "foo: " + num );
}

foo.count = 0; 
console.log(foo.count);
```

It does not matter which kind of object `foo` is, as long as it is [not read-only](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze), you can add or overwrite a property with something like `foo.count = 0`.

Now, to your actual example: it seems like `foo.count` should keep a count of how many times the function is called, but it will not work, because `this` does not refer to the function, but to the global object (i.e. `window` when running in a browser).

To fix that, the function could look like:

```
function foo(num) {
    console.log( "foo: " + num );
    foo.count++;
}
```

...but that is not generic, as you need to "hardcode" the name of the function.

Another way is using a closure, for creating a function with a `count` method instead of a numeric property (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7537126/have-a-javascript-function-privately-track-its-number-of-calls)):

```
var foo = (function () {
    var count = 0;
    // Create the actual function
    var f = function (num) {
        console.log( "foo: " + num );
        count++;
    };
    // ... and give it the count method
    f.count = function() {
        return count;
    }
    // Return that function (it will be assigned to foo)
    return f;
})(); // immediately execute the above code: it returns a function

foo(2); // this increments count from 0 to 1.

console.log(foo.count()); // 1
```

Comment: You should not even *mention*  `arguments.callee` to newbies. It's deprecated and forgotten, please leave it that way.

Comment: Thank you for your kind remark, @Bergie. Although I had clearly mentioned the deprecated status, I have replaced it now with another non-deprecated solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have kind of answered the question yourself.

Functions are also Objects.

In the first step you define the function like so

```
function foo(num) {
  console.log( "foo: " + num );
  this.count++;
}
```

Calling `foo.count = 0` will now just create a property on the Object foo. To read more about Objects in Javascript read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

One thing to be aware of in your example is how you call the function foo. Because the `this` will be different depending on how you call it.

Pasting your example in your browsers console and then calling foo.count will print 0.

This is because `this` will be bound to the Global Context. Read up on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).

As an exercise you could try to figure out how to make the counting work correctly.